# Email not being sent via localhost with Python on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, smtp

I have the following simple code to send an email:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
server.set_debuglevel(1)
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
server.quit()
```

However the message never gets sent.  I added the "set_debuglevel" line in an attempt to troubleshoot but the output doesn't mean much to me:

```
send: 'ehlo [127.0.1.1]\r\n'
reply: '250-ubuntu\r\n'
reply: '250-PIPELINING\r\n'
reply: '250-SIZE 10240000\r\n'
reply: '250-VRFY\r\n'
reply: '250-ETRN\r\n'
reply: '250-STARTTLS\r\n'
reply: '250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\r\n'
reply: '250-8BITMIME\r\n'
reply: '250 DSN\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: ubuntu
PIPELINING
SIZE 10240000
VRFY
ETRN
STARTTLS
ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
8BITMIME
DSN
send: 'mail FROM:<info@foobarconsulting.com> size=337\r\n'
reply: '250 2.1.0 Ok\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: 2.1.0 Ok
send: 'rcpt TO:<adam@foobarconsulting.com>\r\n'
reply: '250 2.1.5 Ok\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: 2.1.5 Ok
send: 'data\r\n'
reply: '354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>\r\n'
reply: retcode (354); Msg: End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
data: (354, 'End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>')
send: 'Hello!\r\n\r\nThe below URLs are either broken or taking too long to respond:\r\nhttp://www.google.com/does-not-exist/\r\nhttp://www.cnn.com/does-not-exist\r\n\r\nLog in and navigate to http://blahblah.com/wp-admin to update the content.\r\n\r\nThanks,\r\n\r\nYour friends at Foo Bar Consulting\r\n.\r\n'
reply: '250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as E7B8820144\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: 2.0.0 Ok: queued as E7B8820144
data: (250, '2.0.0 Ok: queued as E7B8820144')
send: 'quit\r\n'
reply: '221 2.0.0 Bye\r\n'
reply: retcode (221); Msg: 2.0.0 Bye
```

I have installed postfix (I believe it was installed by default when I set up my Ubuntu with the standard LAMP packages) but I don't know where else to go for help.

Any insight or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. you might want to check out sendmail's log
2. make sure your local DNS works. try `ping foobarconsulting.com`

Comment: I can ping the domain from my Ubuntu server.  Unfortunately the sendmail log doesn't even have anything for today's date (Jun 10), which doesn't make much sense either.